# How to start node server when React app starts in production

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How can I start a node js server together with my React App in production environment? I need to call some endpoint provided by the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concurrently`, which can be installed as devDependency. With this you can execute multiple commands with a `scripts` entry

```json
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"yarn start-app\" \"yarn start-server\"",
    "start-app": "...",
    "start-server": "..."
  }
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
...
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I execute the script 'starts' in production? Who will execute it? As I know those scripts are for dev environment.

Comment: When you start the node backend your server should provide NodeJS as runtime environment. With this you can start it with a service entry or batch command at server start up, depending on your OS. When you use yarn build from create-react-app you will get static files which can be served from any http server, e.g. Apache, nginx,...

Comment: As stated in the other answer the static files can also be served by the node service itself.  Depends on your use case and environment.

Comment: My react app is running as outlook web add-in

Comment: I'm not sure what this add-in is capable of but for a backend service you need some kind of real server with some processing power, RAM, domain etc.

Answer (score 0):

In nodeJs main/router file add the following line
1.app.use(express.static((path.join(__dirname, '../../react_client/build'))));
where the second parameter is the path to react index.html file in the build folder. If this line not added will obtain error "unexpected tocken "<" in chunk.js*

2. app.get('*', (req,res) =>{
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../react_client/build', 'index.html'));
   });
   Add this line to handle every get command in the top of every routing function. So that for every get request server will send index.html file
   in package.json of node js server add the following
3. "build": "cd ../../react_client && npm install && npm run build"
   where after cd provide the path for react application. So when run "npm run build" from server terminal react application will build and files are available in the build folder

Inside the  tag of index.html add `"<base href="/" />"` else there will be an error "unexpected tocken <" in bundle.js*

In package.json of react application add "proxy": "http://localhost:9000"; this for communicate with Node js where replace 9000 with your node js listening port

Go to node js server directory and run node server_file name
open browser and enter http://localhost:9000/ will provide your index.html file